# How to type a char and wait for certain ammout of time in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm currently trying to write a function in Obj-C which allows me to type a char (into a NSTextField), wait for e.g. 30 Milliseconds and type the next char of a NSString.
eg;

```
NSString * st = @"hello, world";
NSTextField * tf;
char curr;
int index = 0;
int i;

for(i=0;i<[st length]; i++){
    curr = [st characterAtIndex:index];
    index++;
    //Now append the char to the NSTextField tf;
    //Wait 30 milliseconds
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this within a single function will block the UI unless you go through all the trouble of running the runloop yourself. The idiomatic solution is just to use an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: This means I can't do this as I used before in C#?  Not nice, but thanks

Comment: If you put a wait inside your above loop it would block the thread in C# as well - though the system's use of threads for the UI is somewhat different under .NET you're still in general going to reduce responsiveness. There are alternatives to `NSTimer` if it doesn't suit, e.g. `NSOperation` for the loop and `performSelectorOnMainThread` for the character insert.